# Looking for a good photo gallery slide show tool for my site

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, photo-gallery

I am looking for a easy to use and easily changeable photo slider. I really just want to have 4-6 photos that change every ten seconds or so in a stationary box display. Kind of like a photo gallery, but all changing on the back end and without any thumbnails. I also would like to be able to put text links on the images as well as have full css control on styling and sizing.

Any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

[AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/)

You can put anything images, text, links or whatever you want.

Comment: do you know of one that changes photos on its own? without numbers or arrows? thanks!

Comment: @lightingwrist: There are a host of such solutions out there, i can't remember the name; you can find on google :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own using Dojo, but I'm sure you could do the same thing in jQuery.  I used an article by David Walsh using Mootools as a basis.  It's [here](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-slideshow). If nothing else, the html and css he gives are useful.